# how to display content instead of download as a file when firing GET Request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a webpage which will display API response in tabular format. I developed this using Angular Js, Sevlets, Java- Rest Assured framework.

Each record in the table has a link to a log file which is an url coming as rest api response.

When I give it as an anchor tag and when I click it from the UI a file is getting downloaded instead of openning in a popup window.

My question here is how can I get the data from url instead of download it as file when user clicks on the link.

```
<td> <a ng-href="{{item.outputuri}}" target="_blank">Click Log
 </a>

                                 </td>
```

I have read several posts and got to know that we need to set content disposition at server side. But Its not possible so I want to handle it from Client side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to going to a separate url, how about displaying the content directly on the same page?  You can display the content by dynamically creating an IFRAME element and inserting into host directly on your page.

The `displayContent` method below requests the url and then passes the content to `createIframe`.  That method will create the IFRAME element and write the content to it.  I added the base element to the content to make sure any relative links are rendered correctly.

```
this.displayContent = function(url) {
    $http.get(url).then(res => this.createIfram(url, res.data, this.hostElem);
}

this.createIframe = function(baseUrl, content, appendToElem) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.className = 'content';
    appendToElem.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write('<base href="' + baseUrl + '" />');
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(content);
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
    // do some other processing on the document
}
```